# Prevent hot-linking to images and files

Tags: php

I have several images and PDF files and i have seen several other sites are directly copying those files to their server. i there a better way to prevent this.

I tried cpanel hotlinking protection but in that case I have to give the link for each URL which is allowed and that is not possible to give. So please advise me better way to protect files from directly copying from other server.

I can not block the IP address as it is coming from several other sources. So IP deny manager option is also not good. htaccess also not doing. Any idea?

Comment: If they can view it, they can copy it. Block both or neither.

Comment: I like to swap those hot linked files with something they don't want. Look at where they are placing the hot linked items and make them "special".

Comment: @DavidGuerra see this page http://songs.hotmentos.com/sukoon-2012_download.shtml  you can find sever4al download link . click there it will start downloading . now copy the same link and diretly enter in browser it will give error page not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **no technical measures** you can take which will be effective. **Don't bother**. As another commenter has said, if you can view it, you can copy it. Period.

If you're keen that only *paying* customers can *easily* access your content, then set up a paywall http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paywall They'd need to "hack" your site, or break your site terms of use to copy it after that - both of which give you the possibly to press criminal charges against them (in most jurisdictions).

Otherwise, you only have (civil) legal options:

Step 1: Ask them nicely to remove the appropriated content (use the webmaster email on their sites).

Step 2: Send a DMCA Notice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act (if you're in the USA) or equivalent for your jurisdiction.

Step 3: Have your lawyer send a cease and desist letter, with warning of lawsuit.

Step 4: File a lawsuit for copyright infringement in the appropriate jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to prevent that. If someone can view the file, they can copy it; that's how the web works.

Comment: i want to block php copy function. manually a user can copy i dont have problem but if they are copying by php copy function i want to block

Comment: @raviloves there is no technical difference that you could detect. Don't bother.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh   see this page http://songs.hotmentos.com/sukoon-2012_download.shtml  you can find sever4al download link . click there it will start downloading . now copy the same link and diretly enter in browser it will give error page not found